# c# Struct inheritance workaround?

Tags: c#, inheritance, struct

First, struct doesn't allow inheritance, maybe they don't allow it to keep it lightweight.

I want to share my approach to implement "inheritance" for struct as the Q&A format.

Here is a simple scenario, I have a struct `Person` (I can make it class, but I want to keep it as struct just for this example), `Student` is a `Person`, but `Student` has an extra info called `University`.

Now assume `Person` has some properties, and I want to make `Student` to have all the properties of `Person` (I don't want to `Ctrl+C`-`Ctrl+V` all the properties of `Person`), but C# won't allow me to inherit struct.

Here is the code for my idea:

```
private struct Person
{
    private string m_name;
    private string m_lastName;
    private string m_eyeColor;
    private string m_hairColor;
    
    public void Walk() => m_leg.Walk();
}

private struct Student
{
    private string m_university;
    
    
    public void Walk()
    {
        m_leg.Walk();
        m_shirt.Show(m_university);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have "thousands of properties", it's very unlikely that it's a good idea to make that a `struct` in the first place. Value type semantics mean all of those thousands of properties need to be copied around when the value is. What exactly do you think a `struct` is buying you here, over (say) a class-based `record`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert - "thousands of properties" is a joke, the main idea is I don't want to copy paste the code, but I want to "inherit" it.

Comment: Even "more than a dozen" properties would be a good reason to reconsider having a value type. Again, why are you using a `struct`? There's often a misconception that `struct`s are somehow magically "faster" or that they "consume less memory" than classes, but these are gross oversimplifications that often lead to misapplication. Properly using `struct`s should be considered a specialized topic for optimization and not done for mundane types, especially not if they benefit from inheritance, which is sort of a giveaway you don't want a value type.

Comment: A `struct` is the wrong tool for what you want to do. What specifically do you think a struct will give you that a class won't, for your expected usage?

Answer (score -2):

Here is the idea to solve it:

- To make all the data of `Person` available for `Student`, you can put
  the `Person` inside the `Student`.
- But how about I want to make polymorphism work too: I can use
  `interface`.

Here is the code:

```
interface LivingBeing
{
    void Walk();
}

private struct Person : LivingBeing
{
    public string m_name;
    public string m_lastName;
    public string m_eyeColor;
    public string m_hairColor;
    
    public void Walk() => m_leg.Walk();
}

private struct Student : LivingBeing
{
    public Person m_person;//Here is the data of Person
    public string m_university;
    
    
    public void Walk()
    {
        m_person.Walk();
        m_shirt.Show(m_university);
    }
}

//Now how to use it
void Main()
{
    var lst = new List<LivingBeing>();
    
    Person tommy;
    Student jimmy;
    
    //assign tommy data...
    tommy.m_name = "Tommy Vercetti";
    //... assign other data ...
    
    //assign jimmy data...
    jimmy.m_person = tommy;//Copy thousands of data
    jimmy.m_person.m_name = "Jimmy Hopkins";//Edit the needed data
    jimmy.m_university = "Bullworth Academy"//Assign extra data
    
    //Add to list
    lst.Add(tommy);
    lst.Add(jimmy);    
    
    //Now let's do the polymorphism thing
    foreach(var item in lst)
        lst.Walk();//Now they all walk in their own style
}
```

Comment: 1) this is called composition and it is quite popular approach hence the [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) 2) working with structs via interface (`new List<LivingBeing>()`) will result in boxing negating the benefits of using `struct`'s , just use classes (unless you have constrained generic methods like `Walk<T>(T inst) where T: LivingBeing` ) 3) follow standard naming conventions, i.e. prefix interfaces with `I` - `interface ILivingBeing`

Comment: @GuruStron Even if you use generics, if you constrain to the interface and then use the interface method it'll still need to box the struct.  The generics can only avoid boxing when no virtual methods (namely methods on constrained interfaces or methods on `object`) are used.  The boxing is needed for the virtual dispatch.

Comment: @Servy Are you sure? That [ends up](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwGEBDXXAMQggAoA7GAdwAIBlagSnYG4BYAKH4ABFExJlKEADwAVAHzVpTbLQDOGdkwYALGLCaKQTAJL8A3vyaWlqjADoJHXnwC+/fsoy6AZsTAxjZhZWwkwO3PyuAnxqUACuYBisTIYmfOZ8VkyCAMxZImFMppGRQA===) as a constrained virtual call, and those [don't box in this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained?view=net-7.0). It **does** need to box for methods on `object`, which is why `((int?)null).GetType()` famously throws an NRE

Comment: @Servy in addition to canton7 comment - [my quick take on the issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i4LUBf)